# Invalidate SSLSessions in Android/OkHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp, java-security

I need to support potentially using multiple different client certificates against the same host in my app, so in order to do this I assumed the best approach was to invalidate any existing SSLSessions before using another client certificate.

However the simplest approach: getting the sessions from the sslContext and invalidating them, throws an UnsupportedOperationException (it appears to be a [NativeSSLSession](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/NativeSslSession.java))

```
Enumeration<byte[]> ids = sslContext.getClientSessionContext().getIds();
while(ids.hasMoreElements()) {
    sslContext.getClientSessionContext().getSession(ids.nextElement()).invalidate();
}
```

For some reason it DOES work if I get the session from the socket in an interceptor, but obviously invalidating the session at that point is too late (here it is a [Java8ExtendedSSLSession](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/Java8ExtendedSSLSession.java))

```
builder.addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
    ((SSLSocket)chain.connection().socket()).getSession().invalidate();
    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
});
```

My final approach, which appears to work, is to set the session time out to the lowest possible duration of 1 second (0 is infinite) and then waiting 1 second, but obviously this is a really ugly and hopefully unnecessary hack:

```
int prevTimeout = sslContext.getClientSessionContext().getSessionTimeout();
sslContext.getClientSessionContext().setSessionTimeout(1);
Thread.sleep(1000);

//Do something while the sessions are expired

sslContext.getClientSessionContext().setSessionTimeout(prevTimeout);
```

Is there a better way to invalidate these sessions, or maybe a different approach to this problem?